# Is there any plugin that I should use in order to read MRZ codes in Nativescript Angular

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am using Nativescript Angular to develop my app for Android and iOS. One requirement is to read a **passport MRZ** (machine-readable zone) code using the device camera. My question is: Is there any plugin that can do this or what do you recommend me?

[Passport and MRZ image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejB9f.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is one at the moment. There are several libraries out there for iOS / Android which you could directly use in your project or extend to a {N} plugin.

Comment: Can I access those libraries with IntelliSense using Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Yes, if you generate the typescript declarations for those libraries like explained here - [Android](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/generating-typescript-declarations#android-dts-generator) / [iOS](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries)